# What's the deal with Tek Knight's adaptation from "The Boys" comic book series into "Gen V"?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-boys-2019, the-boys, gen-v

In the original comics of *The Boys*, Tek Knight is clearly a parody of Iron Man. Like Iron Man, Tek Knight wears a high-tech armor suit that gives him enhanced abilities and weapons. Tek Knight is also a member of Payback, a superhero team that parodies the Avengers, of which Iron Man is a founding and core member.

However, *The Boys* TV series spinoff *Gen V* introduces a very different version of Tek Knight in Season 1's fourth episode, “The Whole Truth”. Instead of being a hero wearing a suit of armor, he is the host of a true crime show who possesses superhuman deduction and sensory skills. His suit is never mentioned or shown, and he has no affiliation with Payback, whose members appeared in the third season of *The Boys* TV series. Moreover, he displays a bizarre obsession with holes of any kind. As far as I can tell, there's nothing Iron Man or Tony Stark about him.

**So what is going on with Tek Knight's adaptation in *Gen V*?** Is he still a parody of Iron Man, but in a different way? Or is he spoofing another comic book character? If so, who could it be?

Comment: "Moreover, he displays a bizarre obsession with holes of any kind." explained in the episode and the writers of The Boys seem to use any opportunity to inject juvenile sexual humor (or disgust) into the narrative. It fits with the source material at least.

Comment: @jcollum I thought the obsession with holes thing was a reference to a comic book character.

Comment: no they said in the episode he had a brain tumor that was causing it

Comment: @jcollum Yeah, I know. What I meant was that, at first, I thought that bit was a parody, spoof, or joke referencing a comic book character. It turns out it wasn't, apparently.

Comment: RisingZan below says the comic character has a sexual psychosis so this seems like just a variation on the comic character (and a convenient out for the university's provost to get out of her predicament). So it's in-line with the character and made the story flow easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [an interview with Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/tv/tek-knight-explained-the-boys-gen-v-fascist-batman/), Eric Kripke explains that Jessica Chou, the writer of episode four, imagined Tek Knight **as a Batman parody instead**:

> "Her pitch was, '**Let's make him more Batman than Iron Man**.' He's a combo of both," Kripke continues. "He has his own underground cave, [but] instead of Tony Stark, if we made him the world's greatest detective, then he doesn't need a big, crazy suit. We can have fun with true-crime shows and the inherent fascism of Batman."

Comment: This doesn't mention the obsession with holes at all, but the comic Tek Knight has a sexual psychosis that causes him to have spontaneous relations with both living creatures and inanimate objects.

Comment: I wonder what they view as the "inherent fascism of Batman"

Comment: @guest Especially considering that an important motif of *The Dark Knight Returns* was the inherent fascism of *Superman*.

Comment: @guest - It's an imprecise allusion to the fact that certain incarnations of Batman display a tendency to spy on everyone all the time and have secret weapons to eliminate anyone who could become a threat, which, combined with his very "tough on crime" ideas, has a certain resonance with fascism. Whether it's *inherent* to Batman is questionable—the vigilante approach to crime that has been core to Batman since the beginning is not particularly progressive, and arguably reactionary, but that is not the same as fascism.

Comment: Fascism is always hostile to "undesirable elements" in society,  but not every philosophy that is hostile to such things is fascist. Batman's vaunted rule against killing anyone, for instance, would sit uneasily with most fascists. Even at his most intrusive and prying, Batman's main point of intersection with fascism is totalitarian tendencies. But to be a proper fascist, he'd have to have some nationalist/racist and expansionist ideas, at minimum (Stalin was also totalitarian, spied on everyone, and killed his enemies, but is not generally considered fascist).

Comment: @Adamant if you're looking for people who know what words mean, TV writers aren't the best choice.